# change year after month of december

Tags: javascript

I'm fresher in javascript.

```
var i = 0;
 var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September", "October", "November", "December" ]; // Store month names in array

function Next(id) {
    i++;


    if (i > 12) {
        i = 1;
    }

    $('#monthname').empty().append('<div id="r'+ i +'" class="monthname">'+months[i-1]+'</div>')

    if( months[i-1] == "January"){
        alert(1);
            var year = new Date().getFullYear()+i;
            $('#year').empty().append('<div id="r'+ i +'" class="year">'+year+'</div>')
    }
}
```

This is the code from where I can get the current month and year. While coming on January month, I can get new year of 2014. But again when coming on January, I can't get the new year of 2015. I can get the alert. But year is not replace by the next year.

Comment: FYI You did not accepted ANY of your previous **24 questions** Sweeta. Accepting answers is a way to say *thanks* here on StackOverflow. Commenting on answers is also a way to get the most precise answer or at least a sign that we got your attention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` only succeeds when i is 1, so `new Date().getFullYear() + i` will always be 2014 (till Wednesday). Here's a simpler corrected version of your code:

```
var ym = 12 * new Date().getFullYear() + 11;
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September", "October", "November", "December"];

function Next(id) {
    if (++ym % 12 == 0) {
        var year = ym / 12;
        $('#year').html('<div id="y'+ year +'" class="year">' + year + '</div>');
    }
    var month = ym % 12 + 1;
    $('#monthname').empty().append(
        '<div id="m'+ month +'" class="monthname">'+months[month - 1]+'</div>');
}
```

I've guessed at good ids for the year and month divs. The existing ones weren't great.

Comment: Use `--ym`. You'll have to fiddle the logic for when to output year divs because you're going backwards.

Comment: when i get January the year will change..not on the December... i changed in     if (--ym % 12 == 0) {
        var year = ym / 12 -1;
}

Comment: @Sweeta: Ask yourself what condition would signal that the year has changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833640/how-can-i-change-days-div-positon-on-button-click-event-using-javascript

Comment: @Sweeta: What's the relevance of that link?

Comment: hello...happy new year..now,above code is not going to work...as the new year is started,the if condition is going to true.and the year is changed on next clicked event..i mean to say the current year is 2014,while clicking on next it will displayed 2015..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want a counter in months, this would work

```
var i = 0;
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September", "October", "November", "December" ]; // Store month names in array

function Next(id) {
   var d= new Date();
   d.setMonth(i);
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  $('#monthname').empty().append('<div id="r'+ i'" class="monthname">'+months[d.getMonth()]+'</div>');
  $('#year').empty().append('<div id="r'+ year+'" class="year">'+year+'</div>');
  i++
}
```